# UIView Issue in swift2.0

Tags: uiview, swift2, xcode7-beta4

I have created a uiview in storyboard and have placed it in some random point(autoLayout not applied) . Now in viewDidLoad() Im trying to place it at the center of the screen. But its not moving from that place and replaced at center Why? is this because of some order viewController Life Cycle ? But when I Create a UIView programmatically and placed it in center it works .??

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view1.center = view.center

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. You need to do this in `viewWillAppear`. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is also a good place to put this.

Answer (score 1):

use viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.view1.center = self.view.center
```

}